# How to Get Frame Accurate Seeking from Video HTML Element?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

How do you get a frame accurate count of where you are located in a `<video/>` element?

We know that:

- `currentTime` does not give you precise times - See https://github.com/w3c/media-and-entertainment/issues/4

Example displaying browser variability: https://daiz.github.io/frame-accurate-ish/

- Firefox inaccurated 2/25 times
- Chrome inaccurate 8/25 times

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With example here:
https://adhesive-smooth-produce.glitch.me

We're able to see the following works in getting accurate `frame` count across the entirety of the example video - something not able to be done w/ the `currentTime` parameter.

```
  const updateCanvas = (now, metadata) => {
    if (startTime === 0.0) {
      startTime = now;
    }
    
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
    
    let frameOffset = 2
    const frames = Math.round(metadata.mediaTime  * fps) - frameOffset
    fpsInfo.innerText = !isFinite(frames) ? 0 : frames;
    metadataInfo.innerText = JSON.stringify(metadata, null, 2);

    video.requestVideoFrameCallback(updateCanvas);
  };  

  video.src =
    "https://daiz.github.io/frame-accurate-ish/time.mp4";
  video.requestVideoFrameCallback(updateCanvas);
```

`frameOffset` must be determined from seeing what `const frames = Math.round(metadata.mediaTime  * fps)` equals to at `time = 0`.

Thanks to Blog Post: https://blog.tomayac.com/2020/05/15/the-requestvideoframecallback-api/

Comment: Some more detail, especially on corner cases, can be found in the follow-up [article](https://web.dev/requestvideoframecallback-rvfc/).

Comment: On https://adhesive-smooth-produce.glitch.me 
Frame 285 
click >>
jumps to Frame 288 (skipping 286, 287)
click >>
stays on Frame 288
click >>
stays on Frame 288
click >>
stays on Frame 288
click >>
stays on Frame 289

Comment: Yeah we found that while improved, it still didn't produce accurate readings all the time.

Comment: We had to use a workaround in order to determine frame

Comment: I can''t see where you perform seeking in this example. It is just a sequential playback.